# I want to understand what is the ideal max threads size for SIMBA odbc GCP

Tags: google-bigquery

For large data sets what would be the best max threads option with out using storage api to improve performance

Comment: machine learning is about to find such threshold automatically. why don't you use k-means/dbscan with cosine similarity metric?